# I am not retrieving the value

Tags: android

```
ArrayList<Object> push = new ArrayList<Object>();
pin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
push.add("amam");

JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
try {
    json.put("uniqueArrays", new JSONArray(push));
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

JSONObject jsosn = new JSONObject();
JSONArray items = jsosn.optJSONArray("uniqueArrays");
Log.d("retrived values",String.valueOf(items));
```

I am trying to insert array list and retrieve it. Can anyone help me with best method or guide me in the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new JSONObject on the line above.  That gets rid of the old one and leaves you with an empty object.

Comment: Delete the line above the access where you create a new JSONObject